# What does it mean when I assign an instance of a class to an interface variable?

Tags: arrays, list, arraylist

I was wondering if:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>()
```

is a list that uses the list methods but it's built with an ArrayList?

What is its behavior?

I cannot completely understand if I am creating a Queue or a LinkedList with this piece of code,

```
Queue q = new LinkedList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ArrayList implements the List interface. Similarly, a LinkedList implements the Queue interface. What that means is that:

- ArrayList has promised that it will have all the methods it needs to
  behave like a List
- LinkedList has promised that it will have all the methods it needs to behave like a Queue

Because both classes fulfill those promises (they implement the interfaces), Java can treat an ArrayList like a List. Similarly, it can treat a LinkedList like a Queue.

Why would you want to do this? You might want to be able to pass any List into your code - you don't care how it's implemented. So you might have a HugeSparseList that also implements List that stores underlying objects completely differently. That doesn't matter to your code - as long as the API is the same, your code will still work.

Comment: then if we create something like this, List l = new ArrayList(); it means that we can't call the methods of the array list, just the ones on the list interface?

Comment: That's right, you are promising to treat the object as a List - so your code won't rely on its underlying implementation, just the fact that it has the same behavior as a List.

Answer (score 0):

List is the base class representing a sequence of elements. Array List is a particular implementation that uses an internal array and dynamically allocatez the space when required.
Linked list is a sequence of elements stored by using pointers pointing  from one node to the following.

The two data structures are different in term of computational complexity, memory requirement and speed.
You may find more information [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).